# how to create a table with different type values ​with Parse method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public class Libro
    {
        public string Titolo { get; set; }
        public string Autore { get; set; }
        public string Editore { get; set; }
        public int ISBN { get; set; }
        public int Pagine { get; set; }
        public decimal Prezzo { get; set; }
        public int Quantità { get; set; }
```

not being all of type string, I would not know how to convert the int and decimal values ​​to have as a result a table in which to display a list of books (titles, authors, publishers and price) that I have on a file.txt

```
        public Libro BuildLibro(string input)
        {
            Libro result = null;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                var inputArray = input.Split('*');

                if (inputArray.Length >= 6)
                {
                    result = new Libro();

                    result.Titolo = inputArray[0];
                    result.Autore = inputArray[1];
                    result.Editore = inputArray[2];

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputArray[3]))
                    {
                        int.TryParse(inputArray[3], out int num);
                        result.ISBN= num;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputArray[4]))
                    {
                        int.TryParse(inputArray[4], out int num);
                        result.Pagine = num;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputArray[5]))
                    {
                        decimal.TryParse(inputArray[5], out decimal num);
                        result.Prezzo = num/100;

                    }
                   
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputArray[6]))
                    {
                        int.TryParse(inputArray[6], out int num);
                        result.Quantità = num;

                    }

                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Foreword

**The question has been edited massively since this answer was posted**. I've advised that the edits should be reverted so this answer remains valid for the question as posted prior to the edit on Feb 14th (Revision 3), and a new question posted containing Rev 3's text

#### Original advice for Revision 2

You've switched tactic when you got to ISBN

```
ISBN = 4, Pagine = 5, Prezzo = 6, Quantità = 7
```

Assigning the editore name like this makes sense:

```
Editore = content[3]
```

It means "take the fourth element of the `content` array, which is a string array, and put it in the editors property, which is a string"

I guess you'll have tried the pattern of:

```
ISBN = content[4]
```

But this won't have worked out because `content` is full of *strings* and ISBN is an `int` and even if a string purely only full of numerical chars *that doesn't mean it's a number*. This will have given some error like "there is no implicit conversion..."

I guess then you removed the content and just left a hard coded 4 assigned as the ISBN which will *work* in that it will compile syntactically, but it is incorrect logically. That will just fix every ISBN at being `4`, literally

Instead you should parse the string to an int. it's easy, and we can do it with like:

```
ISBN = int.Parse(content[4])
```

Similarly for the decimal there is a decimal.Parse

This may expose other problems like, if one of the values contains some non numerical chars (e.g. ISBNs that have hyphens in) but we can solve that later...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it went... Thank you. So just change this way?
libri.Add(new Libro { Titolo = content[0], Autore = content[2], Editore = content[3], ISBN = int.Parse(content[4]), Pagine = int.Parse(content[5]), Prezzo = 6, Quantità = int.Parse(content[7]) }); unfortunately there will be errors somewhere else because it doesn't work... can you think of something?

Comment: Really depends what those errors are. Tell me and I'll think of something

Comment: I modified the code above and described the issues

Comment: I cannot understand what the problem is; I can see what your edits are, but they do not seem to describe a problem

Comment: I can't find the error, the problem is that when I execute the code I get error 404. The template item passed in the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]', however the dictionary requires a template element of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[WebSite.Models.Book]'.

Comment: That error is usually because you've said something like `@model Person` in the cshtml and then done e.g. `return "Joe Biden"` in the View; you promised a Person and sent a string. Look at wha tyou;ve put after @model, and then what you;ve returned in the view

Comment: In the HomeController: public ActionResult About()
        {
            List<string> libri = Utility.Reader.Read("C:/Users/test/source/repos/WebSite/WebSite/App_Data/Libri.txt");
            return View(libri);
        } and in the About.cshtml @model List<Libro>

Comment: There you go; you're returning a list of string when you promised it would be a list of Libro

Comment: Right! I modified the above code again, now the table comes out but only with the <th> Title / Author / Publisher / Price </th> ... but the relative values ​​do not (so to speak, from foreach onwards in About.cshtml)

Comment: Right! I changed to: public ActionResult About() {List<Libro> libri =ReaderBook.Read("C:/Users/test/source/repos/WebSite/WebSite/App_Data/Libri.txt"); return View(libri); }  Now the table comes out but only with the <th> Title / Author / Publisher / Price </th> ... but the relative values ​​do not (so to speak, from foreach onwards in About.cshtml)

Comment: It's really hard to diagnore from such small scraps of information. It would be better to post an edit to the question. If `ReaderBook` is a `ReaderR` then it sounds like your code is getting an exception, and so the exception handler is running, doing `libri = new List` so the list is empty and then the cshtml has nothing to show (the foreach never runs).. or your file is empty. Use the debugger to single step through the `Read()` method and see what happens; see what is inside `libri` just before you call `return View`. Do you know how the debugger works?

Comment: Hey man you have been a great help to me however I have tried to do it all over again to make it easier for me (I'm inexperienced yet XD). Now I have edited on and explained where I am, take a look?

Comment: I think it's no longer the same question now? You're asking about how to link off to another page about the book? If so, you should hit EDIT on the question, copy the entire content, post a *new* question with that content, rollback your question here to the previous version and hit accept on this answer. Question edits should not be so drastic that they invalidate existing answers

Comment: thanks for the tip, i did

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to parse information out of a string.

I would sugest using regex. For example with the following regex you could parse three strings separated by a *:

```
(?'Title'[^*]+)[*](?'Author'[^*]+)[*](?'ISBN'[^*]+)
```

The Advantage of using regex is, that you check if the string is valid while the string is parsed.
To test a regex I would sugest to use something like https://regex101.com

In your code you can use the C# library:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?'Title'[^*]+)[*](?'Author'[^*]+)[*](?'ISBN'[^*]+)",
          RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Define a test string.
string text = "Harry Potter*Rowling*12345";

// Find matches.
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
```

Comment: sorry but I'm even more confused, could you contextualize it / insert it directly into the code of the class? I don't know if I made myself well understood in the description ... the end result should be a table with every Title-Author-Price. (so I have to accept the price which is int)